# Beginner HTML5 path/to/jsFile. Unable to load script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble running some JS inside a html5 body.
Here's what's happening, whenever I remove all instances of the arrays from the JS file I am using, the script loads fine in the index file, however, when I add src to the attribute and/or mention an array name from said file, it breaks. simple as that.

since I'm planning on making a pretty big site, I have already begun organizing my root.

here's a little demo:

```
rootFolder/
index.htm
js/targetJS.js
```

here's the code

```
<script src="js/targetJS.js" type="text/javascript">

                document.writeln("<table id='services' class='services' name='services'>");
                document.writeln("<tr>");
                document.writeln("<th> Preview: </th>");
                document.writeln("<th> Description: </th>");
                document.writeln("<th> Cost: </th>");
                document.writeln("</tr>");

                var i = 0;
                //for ( i = 0; i < servicePrev.length; i++)
                {

                    if (i % 2 == 0){
                        document.writeln("<tr class='even' id='even'>");
                        }
                    else{
                        document.writeln("<tr class='odd' id='odd'>");
                        }

                    //document.writeln("<td> " + servicePrev[i] + " </td>");
                    //document.writeln("<td> " + serviceDesc[i] + " </td>");
                    //document.writeln("<td> " + serviceCost[i] + " </td>");
                    document.writeln("</tr>");
                }
                document.writeln("</table>");

</script>
```

Whenever i add the src in the attribute and the lines that are commented out, the code does not work, however, when I omit the src and the lines that are currently commented out, the code works fine. even JSfiddle reports it working fine.
The contents of the JS file are 3 arrays with 5 indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

> The script tag has two purposes:
>
> It identifies a block of script in the page. It loads a script file.
>   Which it does depends on the presence of the src attribute. A
>    close tag is required in either case.
>
> The src attribute is optional. If it is present, then its value is a
>   url which identifies a .js file. The loading and processing of the
>   page pauses while the browser fetches, compiles, and executes the
>   file. The content between the  and the 
>   should be blank.

So, the script file should be loaded by dedicated `script` tag without content, the script content should be inserted into another `script` tag, after all if you have other errors you can check in the console of your broswer

```
<script src="js/targetJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                document.writeln("<table id='services' class='services' name='services'>");
                document.writeln("<tr>");
                document.writeln("<th> Preview: </th>");
                document.writeln("<th> Description: </th>");
                document.writeln("<th> Cost: </th>");
                document.writeln("</tr>");

                var i = 0;
                //for ( i = 0; i < servicePrev.length; i++)
                {

                    if (i % 2 == 0){
                        document.writeln("<tr class='even' id='even'>");
                        }
                    else{
                        document.writeln("<tr class='odd' id='odd'>");
                        }

                    //document.writeln("<td> " + servicePrev[i] + " </td>");
                    //document.writeln("<td> " + serviceDesc[i] + " </td>");
                    //document.writeln("<td> " + serviceCost[i] + " </td>");
                    document.writeln("</tr>");
                }
                document.writeln("</table>");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to seperate your  tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="awesomescript.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
    // some awesome code here
</script>
```

Since html5, you are free to name `<script type="text/javascript">` or just use `<script>` for javascript, as text/javascript is default.